# Почему слова "позадуматься" не найдется в словарях?

Tags: перевод

[Есть альбом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UU6LL-pUSQs) певицы Аллы Орловой, под названием "позадумайся". Сам себе думал, что наверняка это глагол, и инфинитив должен быть "позадуматься". Но слова "позадуматься" ни в каком словаре не нашел. Почему нет, и что оно значит?

Comment: Пожалуйста, раскройте свой вопрос - сссылки недостаточно, вопрос должен быть самодостаточным. Приведите конкретную цитату.

Comment: to be precise the album is titled **"Позадумайся"**, i don't think i ever heard such a word, usually you'd hear **ПРИзадумайся**, still this unusual form sounds synonymous to the conventional form but albeit being unusual doesn't sound as odd as the infinitive **позадуматься**

Comment: @shabunc is better now?

Comment: @Wilson thank you very much, this is exactly what I've meant!

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка, why does the infinitive sound odder than the imperative?

Comment: @Wilson guess it's because the combination of prefixes **поза-** in verbs with perfective base (which this infinitive is) is in itself quite rare in modern Russian, it sounds more natural in those with imperfective base (**позадумываться**) because due to the prefix **по-** it bears connotation of repetetive incremental action for which imperfective aspect is more suitable as it implies continuity over time + the reflexive form with the **-ся** postfix (which makes it almost unique), it's not easy to cogently ratonalize it, just my opinion as a native speaker, maybe for others it's different

Comment: *позадумалась* occurs in Krylov's fable ["The crow and the fox"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/19493/moving-the-subject-of-the-sentence-into-a-dangling-participle)

Answer (score 6):

This word is attested in Yefremova's *Современный толковый словарь русского языка*:

> позаду́маться *сов. разг.* призадуматься

which means it's a modern colloquial synonym to *призадуматься* ("to give something a thought, to reflect on something").

Honestly I think it's the other way around, and *позадуматься* actually predates *призадуматься*, and, for sure, it's neither modern nor colloquial, at least not these days.

I personally know the word from Krylov's fable *The Crow and The Fox* (1807), and a brief search in the corpus shows that it was widely used in XIX century but then its usage declined.

Comment: Would you advise to use призадуматься and not позадуматься in most settings today?

Comment: @Wilson: in neutral settings, for sure.

Comment: As it's perfective, does it carry the connotation of arriving at a conclusion? I'm trying to figure out the differences between при-/позадуматься and при-/позадумываться.

Comment: @Wilson позадумываться means задумываться on and off a number of times, or a little bit, or little by little (which is odd), like по(рас)спрашивать, позаписывать, повыкапывать, позаделывать, попришивать etc. but the verb itself is very rare if used at all, it's as unusual as the verb поодеваться applied to a single person in which case it means to be dressing a little bit (without finishing the task), applied to multiple people it means to dress by each one of them, as понапиваться means to get drunk by each one of them

Comment: @Wilson призадуматься and призадумываться differ like all aspect pairs do, the 1st is a one off act, the 2nd one is repetitive or gradual, occurring over time

Answer (score 5):

This word sounds weird because of the insane combination of prefixes:

задуматься = to start thinking

призадуматься = to start thinking a bit

позадуматься = *to start thinking several times without stopping* (!!!)

This does not make a sense: if you mean "to think several times" then you say

подумать

*Starting* thinking several times makes little sense, but even if you wanted to say that, you would use

позадумываться = to fall into thinking several times, each time for a while,

or even

попризадумываться = to fall into thinking a bit several times, each time for a while

Starting thinking several times *without ever stopping* is simply logically impossible!

Answer (score 2):

**Из толкового словаря Ефремовой (2012):**

**ПРИЗАДУМАТЬСЯ** — задуматься на некоторое время, впасть в некоторое раздумье. **ПОЗАДУМАТЬСЯ** — (разговорное) призадуматься.

**С префиксами всё в порядке.**

1) **Префикс ЗА — многозначный**. 1. Указывает **на начало** действия (прыгать — запрыгать) 2. Указывает **на  результат действия, состояния** (лезть — залезть).

**Почему так?** Начало действия  и конец действия — это две **крайние** точки (как бы их общее свойство).

Поэтому ***задуматься*** — это впасть в задумчивое состояние (**достижение результата** действия).

2) **Префикс ПРИ — тоже многозначный.**  6. Указывает на **ограниченное или неполное действие**:  приглушить (звук),  приутихнуть (о ветре). Общее значение ПРИ — это приближение, а неполное действие — это приближение к полному действию.

Поэтому ***призадуматься***  — задуматься немного или на некоторое время.

3) **Префикс ПО — тоже многозначный**. 1. Обозначает действие в течение некоторого, часто **непродолжительного времени**. Побегать, поговорить, поиграть. Общее значение — направленность. Действие  **в направлении полного действия**, отсюда его ограниченность.

Поэтому ***позадуматься***  — задуматься немного или на некоторое время.